# Having trouble with IgnoreCase

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, ignore-case

Hi im having trouble on putting an IgnoreCase to these codes

```
Console.WriteLine("Select a seat that you want to ocupy");
            string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            //replacing array values with X
            for (int row = Arr.GetLowerBound(0); row <= Arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++row)
            {
                for (int column = Arr.GetLowerBound(1); column <= Arr.GetUpperBound(1); ++column)                    
                    if (Arr[row, column].Contains(UserInput))                       
                        {
                            Arr[row, column] = " X ";
                        }                                                                  
            }
```

I'm replacing an 2d array value with "X" via UserInput
Here's my array

```
string[,] Arr = new string[,]
{{"A1" , " A2" , " A3" , " A4" , " A5"},
{"B1" , " B2" , " B3" , " B4" , " B5"}};
```

Comment: please explain a little more where you placed that code and what exception did you received

Comment: i'm trying to put an IgnoreCase in this line                          if (Arr[row, column].Contains(UserInput))

Comment: Please update your code with error

Comment: What error do u get?

Comment: `Arr[row, column].ToLower().Contains(UserInput.ToLower())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Contains does not have the ability to specify a culture or case comparison. Because of this, you will probably want to use [ToLowerInvariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For example:

```
string UserInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLowerInvariant();

...

if (Arr[row, column].ToLowerInvariant().Contains(UserInput))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this instead:

```
Arr[row, column].Contains(UserInput.ToUpper())
```

Using ToUpper() will always compare the uppercase version of the input regardless of its case. Just make sure the array is as you mentioned "i.e. all uppercase"